# Python - openpyxl wb.save() throwing a TypeError

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a .xlsx that I'm trying to edit and then save as a different file name. I call `wb.save("TestReport.xlsx")`, however I'm getting a TypeError. Interestingly, Python does save a .xlsx document with the filename I specify, however Excel can't open it.

[File in Downloads Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHeWK.png)

[Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWLQQ.png)

Here is my code:

```
def formatReport():

    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\awentz\\Downloads")

    files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getmtime)
    report = files[-1]
    logging.debug(str(report))

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(report)
    ws = wb.active


    ws.delete_cols(1, 1)

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=len(ws["A"]), min_col=4, max_col=4):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != "":
                cell.value = float(cell.value) / 1440
                cell.number_format = 20


    wb.save("TestReport.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
expected <class 'str'>
  File "C:\Users\awentz\Desktop\Python Workspace\PullDailyUsageReport.py", line 90, in formatReport
    wb.save("TestReport.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\awentz\Desktop\Python Workspace\PullDailyUsageReport.py", line 102, in <module>
    formatReport()
```

Comment: You should include the complete traceback from the error.

Comment: I thought that was the complete traceback. That's all that's in the error message. Unless you're referring to line 102, where I call the function, but that's literally just `formatReport()`

Comment: The exception must be occurring elsewhere, my guess is when reading the file because it looks like a descriptor exception and there is nothing else in the code likely to raise it.

Comment: The exception occurs where I call `wb.save("TestReport.xlsx")`. If it is a descriptor error, how would I go about addressing that? Sorry, I'm fairly new and not 100% sure what that error means.

Comment: Try commenting out the number format. These must be some kind of string, 20 is certainly meaningless.

Comment: Well I'm converting it to a float, and from what I've read, that's how you format the cells to be in h:mm format, but I may be using it wrong. Let me look into that and report back.

Answer (score 1):

@Charlie Clark was correct. It was the number_format line that was causing the error. I commented that out and the error as gone away.